# Jest not honoring mocking of imported modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

```
// fileImTestingAgainst.js
import theFuncIWantToMock from 'someModule'

export default function whatever () {
  // logging for debugging purposes
  console.log(theFuncIWantToMock)

  const myVar = theFuncIWantToMock(/* args */)
  // ... more stuff
}

// myTest.js
jest.mock('someModule', () => ({
  theFuncIWantToMock: jest.fn()
}))
import theFuncIWantToMock from 'someModule'
import whatever from 'fileImTestingAgainst'

test('do my test', () => {
  whatever()

  expect(theFuncIWantToMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('cat')
})
```

I'd expect my `console.log` to show that `theFuncIWantToMock` to be a `mock` instance, but instead I'm shown the originally defined function. According to the Jest docs, this is how I should be mocking modules. But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

`import theFuncIWantToMock from 'someModule'`

You're importing the **default** module

So that means you need to mock the default. Try changing it to this.

`jest.mock('someModule', () => jest.fn());`

Also another way to mock files is creating the file under `__mocks__` adjacent to where the module is.

Inside `__mocks__/someModule.js`

```
const mockFunc = jest.fn();
export default mockFunc;
```

Inside your test function

```
jest.mock('someModule');
```

Also try using relative path if these aren't node_modules. 
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#mocking-node-modules

Comment: I’ve attempted that as well with no success. The function I’m importing is the default export.

Comment: What if you created a file `someModule.js` in `__mocks__`  https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#mocking-node-modules